# How to create vertical dynamic listview?

Tags: android

I have to create 1 xml which contains

### ImageView           ImageView           ImageView

TextView            TextView            TextView

Pls help me with xml code

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get source code of list view with image view [click here](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

You can use droiddraw to create XML. You can download droiddraw from [here](http://www.droiddraw.org/)
Its very easy to use.

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

Use `droiddraw` to create your application layout and generate xml file.

Comment: sorry but i dont know what is droiddraw

Answer (score 0):

use droiddraw to create your xml. here's a link for that [Droiddraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a relativelayout and position your children as you wish. Using RelativeLayout is preferred  while building complex layout. This ViewGroup avoids unnecessary overhead xml structures, similiar to the old standard

```
<table>
```

in html.
Check out this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html